# Taking the derivative with respect to a function of multiple variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

So I have a very unique application of chain rule (I've been told it's chain rule) that I've never seen before and I really need explained. It relates to a physics problem, but the question is purely mathematical.

Here's the setup. Let z = h(x, y), x = f(y, z), y = g(x)

Then (I've been told) the operator $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$
is given by the following expression:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$
Which is definitely not the chain rule I learned in Calc III.

In a single-variable context, I think it would be:

Let y = f(x), x = g(y)
Then,
$$\frac{d}{dy}=\frac{dx}{dy}\frac{d}{dx}$$

Is there a theorem or proof to this that someone can point me to? I've never learned about this situation before in all of my years of calculus, and it's crucial for a physics problem I'm working on.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Your notation is too vague. When you take the partial with respect to $x$, is everything a function of $x$? Or are the other variables being held constant?

Comment: The partial with respect to x in this case is just the operator. It is not acting on a specific function. x is a function of y and z, and y and z are both functions of x (and each other).

Comment: When I say everything is a function, I mean are $y,z$ functions of $x$ or are they independent variables

Comment: Or better yet, what function space is it acting on? Is it acting on a space of functions of $x,y,z$, a space of functions of only $y,z$, etc? The problem is you are asking for an expression in isolation and such isolation is $\textbf{impossible}$ to give an answer for. The questions about the function space would be addressed by adding more context about the original physical problem.